# Convergence of sequence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $x_n >0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If $x_n\to A$, then $\ln x_n\to \ln A$.
I found the problem answered on these boards , the explanation was a ten dimensional one, however, I am a mere three-dimensional being :<

I will attempt an $\varepsilon -\delta$ solution.
Due to logarithm function being continous we have that:
$$\forall\varepsilon >0, \exists\delta >0 :\forall x\left (0<|x-A|<\delta\Rightarrow |\ln x -\ln A|<\varepsilon\right ) $$
Fix $\varepsilon >0$. Provided that $x_n\to A$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
 $n\geq N\Rightarrow|x_n -A|<\delta$
 from which
 $n\geq N\Rightarrow |\ln x_n-\ln A|<\varepsilon$
which is what we needed.

Comment: Basically that's correct. Note, however, that $A$ might equal $0$ (hence $\ln A = \infty$).

Comment: Oh yes, all of this assuming $A>0$.

Comment: I see; if you assume $A>0$, then your proof is fine.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. The simplest things are most easily overlooked :< You did mean $\ln A =-\infty$, though :)

Comment: Yeah, sure :) ...